# Select the correct input field

Tags: jquery, forms

Maybe I'm working for too long now but I can't figure this one out or maybe I dn't see it anymore ;)

I have multiple forms on one page. Within these forms there is an input field with + and - arrows to update the quantity.

The problem I'm facing is that I can't select the correct input field so when I update quantity in any input field then the script updates all fields instead of the one selected.

So what I have is this:

```
<form class="formProduct" name="form 1234" action=""/>
.... some fields.....

<div class="quantity 1234">
   <input type="text" name="quantity" value="1" />
    <div class="change">
      <a href="javascript:;" onclick="updateQuantity('up');" class="up">+</a>
      <a href="javascript:;" onclick="updateQuantity('down');" class="down">-</a>
    </div>
 </div>
</form>

<form class="formProduct" name="form 4321" action=""/>
.... some fields.....

<div class="quantity 4321">
   <input type="text" name="quantity" value="1" />
    <div class="change">
      <a href="javascript:;" onclick="updateQuantity('up');" class="up">+</a>
      <a href="javascript:;" onclick="updateQuantity('down');" class="down">-</a>
    </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

The Jquery

```
  function updateQuantity(way){

    var quantity = parseInt($('.quantity input').val());

    if (way == 'up'){
      if (quantity < 10){
        quantity++;
          } else {
          quantity = 10;
      }
    } else {
      if (quantity > 2){
        quantity--;
          } else {
          quantity = 2;
      }
    }

    $('.quantity input').val(quantity);
  }
```

I know I have to use one of the classes like "1234" and "4321" to select the correct input field. But I really can't get that to work. I constantly get an [ object object ] error.

Have I missed something?

Comment: Your code for reducing the value is suspect. You're testing for a value greater than 2, but the initial value is 1. If you press a `down` button first the value will go up!

Comment: @Mike W: would it help if I gave you a link? I don't know exactly what you mean...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

place 'this' keyword in onclick function as a parameter and find closest input based on keyword

```
    <script>
        function updateQuantity(item,way){

            var inputField = $(item).closest('.quantity').find('input');
            var quantity = parseInt(inputField.val(),10);

            if (way == 'up'){
              if (quantity < 10){
                quantity++;
                  } else {
                  quantity = 10;
              }
            } else {
              if (quantity > 2){
                quantity--;
                  } else {
                  quantity = 2;
              }
            }

            inputField.val(quantity);
          } 
        </script>

        <form class="formProduct" name="form 1234" action=""/>

        <div class="quantity 1234">
           <input type="text" name="quantity" value="1" />
            <div class="change">
              <a href="javascript:;" onclick="updateQuantity(this,'up');" class="up">+</a>
              <a href="javascript:;" onclick="updateQuantity(this,'down');" class="down">-</a>
            </div>
         </div>
        </form>

        <form class="formProduct" name="form 4321" action=""/>

        <div class="quantity 4321">
           <input type="text" name="quantity" value="1" />
            <div class="change">
              <a href="javascript:;" onclick="updateQuantity(this,'up');" class="up">+</a>
              <a href="javascript:;" onclick="updateQuantity(this,'down');" class="down">-</a>
            </div>
         </div>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Mixing inline JavaScript with jQuery isn't a great idea, try to avoid it.
2. Your logic has a few flaws, and is targeting all `input` elements deriving from class `.quantity`.
3. Always use a `radix` when using `parseInt`.

---

Modify HTML to make it cleaner:

```
<input type="text" name="quantity" value="1" />
... etc
<a href="" class="up">+</a>
<a href="" class="down">-</a>
```

Then just use the following:

```
$(".up, .down").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var input = $(this).parent().prev("input");
  if(this.className === 'up') {
    input.val() < 10 ? input.val(parseInt(input.val(), 10) + 1) : input.val(10);
  } 
  else {
    input.val() >= 1 ? input.val(parseInt(input.val(), 10) - 1) : input.val(0);
  }   
});
```

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/US2EY/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery closest() to find nearest parent div and find the input element whose value has to be updated..
Ex:

```
    function updateQuantity(item,way){
        var nearest = $(item).closest('.quantity').find('input');
        var quantity = parseInt(nearest.val(),10);

        if (way == 'up'){
          if (quantity < 10){
            quantity++;
              } else {
              quantity = 10;
          }
        } else {
          if (quantity > 2){
            quantity--;
              } else {
              quantity = 2;
          }
        }
        nearest.val(quantity);
    }
```

see working demo [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SZ6Rn/)